# Python solver function like excel sheet solver function to predict a and b value based on dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pulp

Excel sheet solver function predicts `a=-12.7705719809672` and `b=4.65590041575483` value based on the following dataframe.

```
Maturity (C-Days) Strength, (Mpa)      x               y   y^2                   (y-x)^2
10.8              23.8             23.8495018161717   -0.6   36                  0.002450429804294
28.2              28.4             28.3164712450952   -1.4  1.96000000000001    0.006977052895941
70.7              32.6             32.5941766134432    2.8   7.84                3.3911830989322E-05
105.0             34.4             34.4398346638965    4.6   21.16                0.001586800447746
```

Calculate dataframe row value by the following the formula.

- `x[i] = -a + b*ln(M[i])`
- `y[i] = S[i] - avg_strength`
- `y^2[i] = y[i]^2`
- `(y-x)^2[i] = S[i] - x[i]`
- `sum(y^2)  = 208.0944`
- `sum((y-x)^2) = 0.011048194978971`

Where

1. `avg_strength = 23.86`  # Avg. Strength
2. `i - Row number`
3. `S - Strength`
4. `M - Maturity`

## calculate R^2

First time assumes `a` and `b` value to calculate `x` and `(y-x)^2`.

```
R^2 = 1 - sum((y-x)^2)/sum(y^2)
```

where must be `R^2 >= 0.9` and predict `a` and `b` value.

> I'm looking solution same as excel solver function in python to
>   predict a and b value.

**My Python Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pulp import LpVariable, LpMinimize, LpProblem,lpSum,LpStatus,lpSum,LpMaximize,LpInteger
import math

m_s_data = {'maturity':[0.1,10.8,28.2,70.7,105.0],'strength':[0.1,23.8,28.4,32.6,34.4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(m_s_data)
strength_avg = round(df['strength'].mean(),2)
df['y'] = df['strength'] - strength_avg
df['y2'] = df['y']**2
y2_sum = sum([df['y2'][idx] for idx in df.index])

x = LpVariable.dicts("x", df.index,lowBound=-100,upBound=100)
y3 = LpVariable.dicts("y3", df.index,lowBound=-100,upBound=100)
mod = LpProblem("calAB", LpMinimize)
a=1
b=1
for idx in df.index:
    x_row_data = -a + b * np.log(df['maturity'][idx])
    mod += x[idx] == x_row_data
    strength = df['strength'][idx]
    mod += y3[idx] == math.pow(strength,2) + x_row_data * x_row_data -2* strength * x_row_data

#R^2 must be greater than or equal to 0.9
mod += 1- (lpSum(y3[idx] for idx in df.index)/y2_sum) >= 0.9
mod.solve()
print(df)

# Each of the variables is printed with it's resolved optimum value
for idx in df.index:
    print(y3[idx].name, "=", y3[idx].value)
```

**Input dataframe:**

[image]

**Excepted output dataframe:**
[image]

Comment: Please organize the question into problem description, input dataset, code, expected output, output that you're getting etc.

Comment: if `y[i] = S[i] - avg_strength` then the `y` value in your first row should be `-23.76`, right?

Comment: From this equation: `x[i] = -a + b*ln(M[i])` we see that we have a system of linear equation Ax = B. So you could use something like `np.linalg.lstsq(A,B)[0]` in order to find `x` (where `x = [a,b]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use any kind of linear solver using a least square algorithm. Here I use `np.linalg.lstsq()`.

```
import numpy as np

#we have a system of linear equation: Ax = b, according to your equation :-x[0] + x[1]*ln(M) = b

M = np.log([10.80000,28.20000,70.70000,105.00000])
A = np.vstack((-np.ones(M.size),M))
b = np.array([23.84950,28.31647,32.59418,34.43983])
x = np.linalg.lstsq(A.transpose(),b)[0]
```

Results:

```
x = array([-12.77023019,   4.65571618])
```

Comment: thanks, @obchardon, it solved my problem, can you explain in more details line by line code.

Comment: You're welcome! You already know that your equation is linear if you take the log of `M`. In your equation there is two parameters (`-x[0] + x[1]*ln(M) = b`), `x[0]` and `x[1]`, we need to find those values so we build a classical system of linear equation. Since `x[0]` is not multiplied by another variable, we always multiply those values by 1 (so the first column in A is always 1 => `-np.ones(M.size)`. Then we use a least square regression `np.linalg.lstsq` in order to find the value of the two parameters.